# Name of anime with a character whose wings wrap around his arms when he's not flying?

Tags: galactic-patrol-lensman

I saw this anime on TV when I was kid. I think there was a space war going on and this guy was trying to bring a message somewhere. He meets a green alien who he befriends. One planet they go to has some round shaped guy that rolls around and electrocutes you on contact.

Does anyone know the name of this anime?

Comment: You said you saw it when you were kid, but can you give us a decade or some similar time frame to help narrow this down?

Comment: It would also help to know what country you lived in when you were a kid since then we can reduce it to looking at shows with TV dubs in that country.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [Galactic Patrol Lensman](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=2140) there's a character called Worsel who has wings that wrap around his arms when not in use.

[image]